# Can I remove the unity launcher completely?

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm using the MacBuntu pack, it's great but whenever I try to drag some icon/file to another place the launcher shows up. Is there a way to make it stop showing up or remove it completely?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Compile it without the launcher:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/719870/compile-unity-without-launcher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, currently there is no way to remove it or stop this functionality. If you don't want the Unity Launcher you will have to remove Unity as the two are not separable.

---

The best you can do to remove the Unity Launcher (though this is probably what you have already done) is:

1. Open the `System Settings`:

[image: Search for and open System Settings]

2. Go to the `Appearance` settings:

[image: Click on Appearance]

3. Then click on the `Behaviour` tab:

[image: Go to the Behaviour tab]

4. And finally turn on the `Auto-hide the Launcher` setting, set the `Reveal location` to `Top left corner`, and drag the `Reveal sensitivity` slider to `Low`:

[image: Configure the auto-hide functionality]

But this is really it, there's not much more that you can do, and if you really want to remove the Unity Launcher then you'll have to remove Unity, and the safest way to do that is just to install [another Ubuntu Flavour](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but as you said I can't remove it, so this is my better shot. Thanks.

Comment: @JLTD: Ok, well if you want to go into Unity's source code and actually manually edit it out and recompile, then sure, you can really do anything with anything. But currently there is no other way of configuring it short from doing as you did and manually editing Unity's source code. You should at least test it on the latest version of Ubuntu and Unity though, because it could have some hidden side-effects, or might completely just not work on later versions or break stuff.

Comment: Just correcting my previous comment (now deleted): As far as I know @ParanoidPanda is right and there is no way to remove the launcher as it is, by means of settings or any tools. But in case you are considering also recompiling unity from source, this could be a solution (I haven't tested it yet on 14.04): http://askubuntu.com/questions/719870/compile-unity-without-launcher

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System Settings` followed by `Appearance`, then Turn On the Auto-hide and set the reveal sensitivity to absolute low.

[image: System Settings]

Comment: I think that the OP has already done this and this is not what they are asking. From my understanding the OP is asking how to stop it from appearing again after you drag a file or something which is not changed by these settings.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it does for me, I've few folders on my desktop.I drag or pull the launcher doesn't show up :/
I'm using 15.10 though

Comment: @kos: I just booted into an Ubuntu 15.10 VM and tried it out.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda You're right, the launcher doesn't show up if hovering on the side of the screen with the mouse, but it still shows up when dragging a file. I suppose that's how it's meant to act.

Comment: @RiashatRafat: And it doesn't react even when you drag stuff in `Nautilus` (because I didn't check the desktop, only `Nautilus` and maybe the Unity Launcher reacts differently)?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Changed my mind, this shouldn't be at the top of the stack. Riashat Rafat I'm sorry but this just doesn't work, at least not in 15.10, dragging the file close to the launcher area makes the launcher show up. Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Seems to work here on 14.04.3 LTS: the launcher does still show up, but moves away so fast it's impossible to drop a file on there by accident!

Comment: @RiashatRafat: You should make the above clearer in your answer...

Comment: Since Fabby confirmed that this works in Trusty, +1 also from me. Sorry for having removed my upvote previously, but testing again in a VM with 15.10 showed that this doesn't work in later versions; as Fabby said you should clarify this in the answer.

Comment: Oh, and leave me a comment after you've edited your answer.... **;-)**

Comment: I have just tested this on 14.04.3 and I am unable to reproduce, for me when I drag a file the Launcher shows up and doesn't go away until I drop the file.