# How to **really** empty dconf com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites?

Tags: unity, launcher, gsettings

I want to completely, unconditionally remove **all** icons from Unity Launcher, so that no icons are ever displayed there. For that, I found out that dconf setting with the key of `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` needs to be emptied. However, when I do try to delete its value, whether through dconf-editor, or with the following Terminal command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites '[]'
```

the value always reverts to the default value of:

```
['unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']
```

Is there a way to leave this key's value empty, i.e. `[]`?

If yes, how can it be done? Also, are there any potential or known negative effects to it?

The reason why I want to do it is because Unity Launcher conflicts with my dock app (Docky). The problem has been reported numerous times since 2012, but sadly there are no indications that it will ever get fixed. That's why I'd like to remove all indicators (icons) and thus stop all activity in the Launcher, if possible.

Comment: Whatever I have tried didn't work (dconf/ glib schema  override & locks ). The only way I know which may work well, needs changes in unity code, may be you are lucky that someone had already faced same issue and built a unity package without launcher :) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/719870/compile-unity-without-launcher