# Can I disable Unity's Search?

Tags: unity, 16.04, unity-dash, search

I'd really like to disable the whole search thingy that pops up on screen on ubuntu 16.04 when you press the Super key.

I like the other UI aspect of the OS, and would like to replace the "Search" panel with Albert or a different program.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebinding "Super" to Albert?

Comment: You will not be able to bind just super to anything else. Find some other suitable binding or don't use unity7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite possible and requires 2 steps:

1. Disable Super from CompizConfig Settings Manager as key for Dash
2. Set custom shortcut

Install CompizConfig first: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`. Open it and navigate to `Unity Plugin`.

[image]

Then unset the shortcut under Launcher tab:

[image]

Finally, go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom -> `+` button and create custom command.

[image]

Once you've clicked `Apply` , click on the `Disabled` text and press the `Super` key to make it now correspond to that command. All done !

Comment: Yes, one can do that but to note it's not just a disabling of the Dash Home, (search). It will also disable all unity super+< key > actions. (exception of super+alt). May not matter here but may for some.

Comment: @doug yes, that's a bit of a trade-off, unfortunately. I can think of a few alternative ways, but this is the closest to what OP asked related to disabling dash and reassigning it to some other command

Comment: If I disable the Unity Plugin it also disables GUI rendering for all of my apps, I'll try replacing the shortcuts only. Is there anything that I can do to remove Unity Dash (search thingy) from the source code itself?

Comment: @razex you're **not** supposed to disable Unity Plugin and I never told you to do so. Disable only the `Key to Show the Dash` shortcut. Please read my answer again carefully.  As for removing Unity Dash, it's tied to launcher, so if you want to remove Dash you will have to remove Launcher. There is question about that and it has answer, but it requires recompiling Unity by yourself : http://askubuntu.com/q/719870/295286